# Accessing the same sqlite in memory database from two different engines in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I "inherited" the following sample code. This is not the actual code but the essence of it

```
Base = declarative_base()
engine1 = create_engine('sqlite://')
engine2 = create_engine('sqlite://')

Session1 = sessionmaker(bind=engine1, autocommit=False)
Session2 = sessionmaker(bind=engine2, autocommit=False)

ScopedSession1 = scoped_session(Session1)
ScopedSession2 = scoped_session(Session2)

scoped_session1 = ScopedSession1()
scoped_session1 = ScopedSession2()
```

I have a bunch of models that inherit from Base and get created using the following

```
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine1)
```

If I do

```
scoped_session1.query(MyModel).all()
```

I get an empty list because nothing was inserted. If I do

```
scoped_session_2.query(MyModel).all()
```

I get

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: reasons [SQL: u'SELECT reasons.id AS reasons_id, reasons.reason_text AS reasons_reason_text \nFROM reasons']
```

I am guessing they create different database in memory so the tables are only created in the first (engine1). I am using in memmory databases in my test cases of my application. Needed to do some refactoring and now I am stuck with this. Is it possible for two different engines to see the same in memory database?

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) says: "If the filename is an empty string, then a private, temporary on-disk database will be created."

Answer (score 0):

As we know `create_engine()` returns an instance of Engine object. So what if define a function which return a cached reference to a previous instance created with same argument:

```
import weakref
_engine_cached = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
def get_engine(engine):
    if engine not in _engine_cached:
        e = create_engine(engine)
        _engine_cached[engine] = e
    else:
        e = _engine_cached[engine]
    return e

engine1 = get_engine('sqlite://')
engine2 = get_engine('sqlite://')
```

Now you will be able to do `scoped_session_2.query(MyModel).all()`